# Alfresco evaluator to get all documents not in a workflow

Tags: alfresco, alfresco-share, evaluator

I'm quite new to Alfresco, pardon my imprecise question.

I have an Alfresco version 5.2.4, with share.

I have a custom action on documents I can call with a button inside document details page, but this button needs to be visible only when that document is not inside a custom workflow I created.

Can I do that with an evaluator? If so, how? Have I to add some custom property to the document model?

Thanks to all

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answer, I should just use 
    evaluator.doclib.indicator.activeWorkflows
basic type